# How to ignore null parameter in a Stored Procedure Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created a stored procedure where the user can inset 1 or multiple values in the parameter

```
create or replace procedure  MyProcerdure
(
title Film.Title%Type,
country Film.country%Type,
language  Film.language%Type,
category  Film.category%Type,
refCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) 
AS 
begin 
 OPEN refCursor FOR
select Film.Title as FilmTitle,
      Film.language as language
       Film.category

FROM Film 
Where Film.language=language
AND Film.category=category
AND Film.Country=country
//etc...
```

But I want to allow the fact that the user doesn't  have to fill them all and pass them in parameter , which means if the user only enter the language without anything else , return the proper language , and let's say he entered country and language so the result should get WHERE language and country is equal to what he inserted

Is it possible to make such a mechanism in a stored procedure using oracle  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add some logic in your query to handle the fact that parameters can be null:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcerdure(
                                         p_title             Film.Title%TYPE,
                                         p_country           Film.country%TYPE,
                                         p_language          Film.language%TYPE,
                                         p_category          Film.category%TYPE,
                                         po_refCursor    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                                        ) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN po_refCursor FOR
        SELECT Film.Title AS FilmTitle, Film.language AS language, Film.category
        FROM Film
        Where ( p_title    is null or Film.title    = p_title   )
          AND ( p_country  is null or Film.country  = p_country )
          AND ( p_language is null or Film.language = p_language )
          AND ( p_category is null or Film.category = p_category );
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to accomplish this is to use dynamic SQL. You can conditionally concatenate the correct filters. You will also want to concatenate an alternate version for when no value was provided.

For example, the following allows you to either filter, or put in a statement that the compiler will ignore but still has the correct number of bind variables in the dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcerdure
(
   title     file.title%TYPE,
   country   file.country%TYPE,
   language  file.language%TYPE,
   category  file.category%TYPE,
   refCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
   l_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   l_stmt := 'SELECT f.title AS filetitle,'||
             '       f.language AS language,'||
             '       f.category'||
             '  FROM file f'||
             ' WHERE 1 = 1';

   IF title IS NOT NULL THEN
      l_stmt := l_stmt || ' AND f.title = :title';
   ELSE
      l_stmt := l_stmt || ' AND (1=1 OR :title IS NULL)';
   END IF;

   -- The others would be done similarly

   OPEN refCursor FOR l_stmt USING title, -- The others would go the same order as above
END;
/
```

Comment: If you're going to use dynamic sql for this, there's no point in adding the predicate mentioned in your `ELSE` clause.

Comment: I believe that dynamic SQL only should be used when nothing else can work. In this case, I think a solution with some boolean logic would be easier and safer.

Comment: @Boneist I'm a bit late to this bit actually without the `else` the code would result in the exception `ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist`

Comment: @Aleksej that can be true, but an advantage of this approach is that you end up running a more appropriate query, which may be optimized better, compared to a static query with lots of predicates like `and (:p1 is null or c1 = :p1)`