# Dealing with NULLs in Oracle

Tags: oracle, null

I have a query that is filtering using the `:CONTRACT_TYPE`. My contract_type contains both nulls and integers.

I cannot seem to deal with the nulls correctly, if I do the following, I return 0 results:

```
 WHERE CONTRACT_TYPE = NVL(:CONTRACT_TYPE, CONTRACT_TYPE)
```

I get the results I want when I simply do:

```
WHERE CONTRACT_TYPE is null
```

I want to be able to pass in the `:CONTRACT_TYPE` with both NULLS and integers.

Thanks all :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle : sql select query if condition parameter is null then ignore the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881633/oracle-sql-select-query-if-condition-parameter-is-null-then-ignore-the-paramet)

Comment: The SQL standard uses `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` for this, which Oracle doesn't support yet. So either use `AND`/`OR` to cover all cases (as shown by Sayan Malakshinov) or use `DECODE` (as shown by bjoern81). I often use `DECODE(contract_type, :contract_type, 'same', 'different') = 'same'` for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get matching results for both nulls and non- nulls, you could try

```
WHERE decode(:CONTRACT_TYPE, CONTRACT_TYPE, 1) = 1
```

Comment: I know its slighty off the topic of this question, but would you then know how to allow this to deal with multiple Ints within :CONTRACT_TYPE? So something like, NULL,1,2,3 being passed in?

Comment: @Fusiozii: As one bind variable contains only one value (Oracle doesn't have an array data type), you need one bind variable per parameter , e.g. `WHERE decode(:CONTRACT_TYPE1, CONTRACT_TYPE, 1) = 1 OR decode(:CONTRACT_TYPE2, CONTRACT_TYPE, 1) = 1`. Or you'd use one string and string funktions, e.g. `where '|' || :contract_type_string || '|' like '%|' || contract_type || '|%'`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually simple

```sql
WHERE 
   (:CONTRACT_TYPE is not null and CONTRACT_TYPE = :CONTRACT_TYPE)
 or 
   (:CONTRACT_TYPE is null and CONTRACT_TYPE is null)
```

works fine.
But sometimes you may have a problems with suboptimimal executions plans when or_expansion/use_concat doesn't work.
In such cases manual or-expansion using `union all` may help:

```
select ... from t where  (:CONTRACT_TYPE is not null and CONTRACT_TYPE = :CONTRACT_TYPE)
union all
select ... from t where  (:CONTRACT_TYPE is null and CONTRACT_TYPE is null)
```

Or there is also another approach - using partially documented function `sys_op_map_nonnull`:
create function-based index on `sys_op_map_nonnull(CONTRACT_TYPE)` and use it in your predicates:

```
where sys_op_map_nonnull(CONTRACT_TYPE) = sys_op_map_nonnull(:CONTRACT_TYPE)
```